# how to do when I am alert that github is behind 1 commit

Tags: github

I using guthub on different PC. clone the same repository, I modified the code and commit change in one PC.  But when I open another PC, it alert me that I am behind 1 commit. how to process this issue?

Comment: Do a `git pull`. Look at the documentation. Pick up a book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the local git repository on the other PC.

Presumably you've already done:

```
git fetch
```

to pull the latest changes. Now you need to merge your local branch with the remote one:

```
git merge origin/master
```

(or whatever branch name you're behind on)

Comment: C:\Users\li\Documents\GitHub\redowxGIS>git merge origin/master
Updating e10314e..ddf7409
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        minimal/wxGIS.suo
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting. How should I do?

Comment: Exactly what git is saying to do, commit what you have, then merge (you have uncommitted changes in your tree) or stash them (set them aside).

Comment: he say i should commit changes or stash. I know how to  commit, but how to stash. I want to stash , and then merge or git pull.

Comment: `git stash` will put your changes aside in the stash.

Answer (score 1):

1. git pull and (merge if needed)

Answer (score 0):

Also probable you started working on an old clone and did a minor commit there, just do a Git pull and that should fix it.